# How to make the browser Url to ReadOnly True using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a requirement to make the browser URL to Read Only true like in the Bank Net banking sites.When the browser open it self opening the URL should be in the read only state like we can read the URL but unable to Modify the URL.Can we do this using javascript?Make sure that am not asking in the window open form please provide me the solution in the direct browser.

Comment: I may be wrong but this sounds like the classical ridiculous request coming from a brain-dead manager that's still using IE6 and has his e-mail printed by his secretary. So I guess that any JavaScript trick that makes it difficult for *him* will do, even if it doesn't add any real security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think you can do this. The browser does not want you to hide the url for anti-spoofing reasons.

You can open a popup windows with location=0 or use a popup control

Comment: +1. It is opening with `location=0` that some browsers render as a read-only address bar. It doesn't get you anything  and has obvious usability problems (as do pop-ups in general). It can't be done on the existing browser window, and good thing too.